# GXT support for GWT designer

Tags: java, gxt, gwt-designer

Will the GWT-designer plugin  in Eclipse support GXT application design (with GXT-3.0)?
If not is Sencha or Google working on this integration for GXT-3.0?
What are the alternate UI-designers available for development with GXT-3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer is not on the roadmap from Sencha GXT3 (according to the Sencha forum), but at the Google I/O 2012 conference, Sencha CEO Michael Mullany spoke at the end of the "History and Future of Google Web Toolkit" session and twice mentioned upcoming support for GXT 3 in GWT Designer.

Check out the session; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOf27ez_Hvg

At 32:18; "We're also happy to be working on GWT Designer integration for GXT."

At 39:00; "Better IDE support and tooling - so there's some support coming in GWT Designer for GXT 3. Our goal is to make it easier and easier to create GXT applications using standard Eclipse and standard IDEs."

Google decided that future GWT development will be controlled by a GWT Steering Committee, and Sencha has a member on the committee. This decision *might* be why GWT Designer integration is back on the table.

Hopefully, there will be more information soon and perhaps an updated Sencha GXT Roadmap.

Comment: Is it implemented?